# postgresql commands not being executed

Tags: linux, postgresql

I downloaded postgresql-9.1.

but when I execute the command in terminal:

```
 $ createdb mydb
```

I get the following message:

```
createdb: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

please tell me how to sort this problem.I have even tried to uninstall and then reinstall it. I am trying to run this on linux mint 15 (cinnamon).

Comment: Did you happen to look at the docs? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/server-start.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ps` to see if the postgresql process is actually running. If not, start it (`service postgresql start`). Normally should start up itself on boot after installation but who knows. Also, some error may prevent it from starting on boot.

If postgresql is running, then you may need to edit `pg_hba.conf` in the data directory. Again, normally the database should listen for local connections by default but who knows.